# Is there a way to check @RestResource usage frequency?

Tags: rest-api, debug-logs, restresource

Can you please tell me, if there is a way to check @RestResource usage frequency?

Short summary: I have a legacy @RestResource which is supposedly not used by anyone. I want to check that.

I have several ideas about it, but maybe there is a better way.

- Create Custom Object Log__c and insert a record every time @RestResource is called.
- Check debug logs with SOQL `SELECT Id, Operation, SystemModstamp FROM ApexLog WHERE Operation LIKE '/resource%'`, but I can retrieve only tiny time range.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: In general logger for API would be a good idea.

Comment: we export our Shield EventLog files to our company's Sumo Logic which has a built in collector for SFDC events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50186/can-i-determine-when-an-apex-class-last-ran) question, Apex execution isn't logged outside of the EventLogFile object, which is not available via Workbench and accessing the logs for Apex execution appears to be part of a paid add-on with a 30 day retention window (the free version is limited to ["insecure external assets, login, logout, and total API usage event log files with 1-day data retention"](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring/event_monitoring_intro)).  Since this would count as Apex execution - and I haven't found any documentation regarding tracking usage of REST endpoints specifically - unless you have this paid feature already and are fine with the 30-day window, I'd agree with Raul; using a custom log object is probably your best bet.

Comment: I have already implemented custom logging, but was hoping to use native SF mechanism. Anyway, it is useful to know about this feature.